# Optimising Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table with data from another table, i want to add missing latitude and longitudes into a 'companies' table where that data is missing. I have a table of postcodes and their corresponding latitudes and longitudes to pull from but i needed to format the companies postcodes correctly (change to upper case, and remove the spaces).

Ideally i would like to do this as one query, so i wrote this:

```
UPDATE companies as c JOIN add_postcodes as p 
    ON p.postcode = UPPER(replace(c.company_postcode, ' ', '')) 
SET 
    company_latitude = add_postcodes.Latitude,
    company_longitude = add_postcodes.Longitude
WHERE company_longitude IS NULL AND company_postcode != ''
```

Which works, but took forever (almost literally)

So i then changed it to update the postcodes in the companies table first and THEN ran the update.

```
UPDATE  companies 
   SET postcode = UPPER( REPLACE( company_postcode,  ' ',  '' ) )

UPDATE companies JOIN add_postcodes 
    ON companies.postcode = add_postcodes.postcode 
   SET company_latitude = add_postcodes.Latitude,
       company_longitude = add_postcodes.Longitude 
 WHERE company_longitude IS NULL AND  company_postcode !=  ''
```

And this was really fast.

Now i think i understand why this is, but i am wondering if i could have rewritten my single query to be fast as well, which would also mean i don't have to alter the columns in the companies table.

I know i could have created an addition column, don't the update then deleted the column but this is more a learning exercise for me than a production ready solution.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: Can you convert the queries to SELECT's and post the query plans?

Comment: @Vatev by query plans do you mean adding EXPLAIN and posting the outputs?

Comment: yes. (few more characters to submit a comment...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first version was slow is because the join clause `p.postcode = UPPER(replace(c.company_postcode, ' ', ''))` has to perform the string manipulation for every single row in the companies table that meets the where clause criteria. If there is an index on the postcode column in the companies table, it won't be used.

You might be able to speed things up by running multiple queries. For instance, if there are a substantial number of records that don't need the string manipulation on the join, you could run:

```
UPDATE companies as c JOIN add_postcodes as p 
    ON p.postcode = c.company_postcode 
SET 
    company_latitude = add_postcodes.Latitude,
    company_longitude = add_postcodes.Longitude
WHERE company_longitude IS NULL AND company_postcode != ''
```

before you run the other query. As this query will set the longitude column, records affected won't match the where clause and *should* be filtered out before the join happens.

Another thing you can try is to leave out the UPPER function - MySQL by default is [not case sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html) when comparing strings. This might go faster:

```
UPDATE companies as c JOIN add_postcodes as p 
    ON p.postcode = replace(c.company_postcode, ' ', '') 
SET 
    company_latitude = add_postcodes.Latitude,
    company_longitude = add_postcodes.Longitude
WHERE company_longitude IS NULL 
AND company_postcode != ''
```